# Salt minion returns no response after being accepted

Tags: salt-stack

After setting up the salt-master and one minion, I am able to accept the key on the master. Running `sudo salt-key -L` shows that it is accepted. However, when I try the `test.ping` command, the master shows:

> Minion did not return. [No response]

On the master, the log shows:

> [ERROR   ][1642] Authentication attempt from minion-01 failed, the public key in pending did not match. This may be an attempt to compromise the Salt cluster.

On the minion, the log shows:

> [ERROR   ][1113] The Salt Master has cached the public key for this node, this salt minion will wait for 10 seconds before attempting to re-authenticate

I have tried disconnecting and reconnecting, including rebooting both boxes in between.

Comment: you tried re-registering the salt-minion?

Comment: Could you share the command you are executing on the master? Something like `salt '*' state.highstate`, I imagine.

Comment: At this point I'm unable to get past the command `sudo salt '*' test.ping`. I am assuming that if the test ping fails, no other commands will execute.

Comment: Possibly a [firewall issue](https://docs.saltstack.com/en/latest/topics/tutorials/firewall.html)? Or, maybe something like SELinux is blocking the communication with the minion?

Comment: Both boxes are debian-based (one Ubuntu, one Lubuntu) so I'm assuming that rules out selinux issues. I have no firewall running, and both boxes are on local networks. I will double-check that UFW or similar didn't somehow get activated though.

Comment: @Toby Did you find any solution? I have the same problem!

Answer (score 6):

```
Minion did not return. [No response]
```

Makes me think the salt-minion process is not running. (those other two errors are expected behavior until you accepted the key on the master)

Check if salt-minion is running with (depending on your OS) something like

```
$ systemctl status salt-minion
```

or

```
$ service salt-minion status
```

If it was not running, start it and try your test again.

```
$ sudo systemctl start salt-minion
```

or

```
$ sudo service salt-minion start
```

Depending on your installation method, the salt-minion may not have been registered to start upon system boot, and you may run into this issue again after a reboot.

Now, if your salt-minion was in fact running, and you are still getting `No response`, I would stop the process and restart the minion in debug so you can watch.

```
$ sudo systemctl stop salt-minion
$ sudo salt-minion -l debug
```

Another quick test you can run to test communication between your minion and master is to execute your test from the minion:

```
$ sudo salt-call test.ping
```

`salt-call` does not need the salt-minion process to be running to work. It fetches the states from the master and executes them ad hoc. So, if that works (returns

```
local:
    True
```

) you can eliminate the handshake between minion and master as the issue.

Comment: Thanks for this - the minion was definitely running, and I had restarted it and rebooted several times during troubleshooting. Running the `salt-call` command on the minion DOES return true though.The debug confirms that the config files and keys are the ones the minion is supposed to be using, and that it's trying to access the master on the correct IP and port.

Comment: in my case I have edited the /etc/salt/minion file and pointed to salt master but forgot to restart salt-minion service. so minion didnt get the change about salt master. After restarting minion all good. Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

I just hit this problem when moving the salt master to a new server, to fix it I had to do these things in this order (Debian 9):

```
root@minion:~# service salt-minion stop
root@master:~# salt-key -d minion
root@minion:~# rm /etc/salt/pki/minion/minion_master.pub
root@minion:~# service salt-minion start
root@master:~# salt-key -a minion
```

*Please note the minion/master servers above.*

Answer (score 2):

If you are confident that you are connecting to a valid Salt Master, then
remove the master public key and restart the Salt Minion.
The master public key can be found at:
`/etc/salt/pki/minion/minion_master.pub`

Comment: Thanks for the response - I tried this and the error remains. The logs show the same thing as before.

Comment: On the master:

`[ERROR   ][1642] Authentication attempt from minion-01 failed, the public key in pending did not match. This may be an attempt to compromise the Salt cluster.`

And the minion:

`[ERROR   ][1113] The Salt Master has cached the public key for this node, this salt minion will wait for 10 seconds before attempting to re-authenticate`

Comment: try deleting the minion key on the master and restarting the salt-minion service

Comment: I ran `sudo salt-key -d` and confirmed the key deletion. Then rebooted the minion, and running `sudo salt-key -L` on the master shows the unaccepted key. I ran `sudo salt-key -a minion-01` and confirmed the accepted key. Running `sudo salt-key -L` shows the key as accepted. However, running `sudo salt '*' test.ping` returns `Minion did not return. [No response]`.

Comment: The errors in the log are identical to the errors in the OP and the comment above.

Comment: have you tried updating the salt packages?I faced a similar issue at onepoint

Comment: and can you take a look at this issue http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.sysutils.salt.user/13547

Comment: there was an update available for the minion, I reset everything, rebooted both and the errors are the same. I checked the minion_id file mentioned in that support thread, it is correct. Thanks for the help, I'm going to kill both boxes and start from scratch.

Answer (score 1):

Minion's public key position under master is 
`/etc/salt/pki/master/minions`

Just compare it with the minions own public key(under `/etc/salt/pki/minion/minion.pub`)

If it is not the same, excute 
`salt-key -d *` 
to delete the public key of minion from master, 
then excute `service salt-minion restart` to restart salt minion on the minion client.
After this, Master can control the minion.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error message.

**I change `user: root` to `user: ubuntu` in `/etc/salt/minion`.**

Stop `salt-minion`, and run `salt-minion -l debug` as `ubuntu` user. salt master could get the `salt-minion` response.

But, when I run `salt-minion` with `systemctl start salt-minion`, salt master got error. (no response)

**I run `salt-minion` as `root` user and `systemctl start salt-minion`, it works.**

I don't know if it is a bug.

Answer (score 0):

I had this exact same problem when I was moving minions from one master to another. Here are the steps I took to resolve it.

1. Remove the salt-master and salt-minon on the master server.
2. `rm -rf /etc/salt` on the master hosts
3. Save your minion config if it has any defined variables
4. Save your minion config if it has any defined variables
5. Remove salt-minion on the minion hosts
6. `rm -rf /etc/salt` on all minion-hosts
7. Reinstall salt-master and salt-minion
8. Start salt-master then salt-minions

My problem was solved after doing this. I know it is not a solution really, but it's likely a conflict with keys that is causing this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Run salt-minion debug mode to see, if this is a handshake issue.

If so, Adding salt-master port(4506 or configured) to public zone with firewalld-cmd should help.

```
`firewall-cmd --permanent --zone=public --add-port=4506/tcp`
`firewall-cmd --reload`
```

Answer (score 0):

Your salt-master keys on minion seems to be invalid (may be due to master ip or name update)
Steps for troubleshoot:-

1. From minion check if master is reachable (simple ping test )
2. Delete the old master keys present on minion (/etc/salt/pki/minion/minion_master.pub)
3. Again try from master to ping minion new valid keys will be auto populated